# Transmission of Poisson process properties: $(N_t :t \geq 0 )$ = P.process $\implies \frac{1}{t+1}N_{t+1}$, $\frac{1}{2}N_{4t}$, (...) = P.processes?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

$(N_t :t \geq 0  )$ is a Poisson process with variable $\lambda$.

- $A_t = \frac{1}{t+1}N_{t+1}$
- $B_t = \frac{1}{2}N_{4t}$
- $C_t = \frac{1}{2}N_{2t}$
- $D_t = \frac{5}{2}N_{t+1}$

Is that true that $A_t, B_t, C_t, D_t$ are also Poisson processes?

I think it should be true since all of them look like scaling of values $N_{t}$ with avoiding some of them. However I have seen that only specific transformations transmission Wiener proces properties. Therefore I would like to know how it works with Poisson processes.

Comment: At least, $A_t$ is not for obvious reason. For the rest, why don't you check the definition ?

Comment: Oh, in $A_t$ the increments are not independent (are not equal). The other are Poisson processes if $N_t$ is a Poisson process, I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use a different definition, none of these are Poisson processes.

A Poisson process can be interpreted as a counting process (i.e. counting the number of events that have happened). Scaling by $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{5}{2}$ is therefore not allowed, as it wouldn't increment by one anymore.

Comment: Ok, so it would be a Poisson process if we did $E_i=N_{2t}$ or $F_i=N_{t+1}$?

Comment: But if $N_t$ increments by one, then $N_{2t}$ increments by 2 and the scaling factor $\frac{1}{2}$ brings that incrementation back to one. @MXXZ

Comment: $E_i$ should be a Poisson process, at least I don't see any immediate problems. $F_i$ is not though, as $F_0 \neq 0$ in general.

Comment: And no, $N_{2t}$ doesn't increment by $2$. What you're doing by having $2t$ instead of $t$ is letting the counting process "move double it's speed". The increments themselves are still only by one.

Comment: Ok, thats interesting. I'm just getting started with all those processes, excuse my silly questions and assumptions. Thank you